# Gender-neutral version of widow & widower?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms, gender-neutral

Would it make more sense to use a third, different word, e.g. "spouse" instead of wife & husband, or use one of them, e.g. "actor" for actor & actress.

"Widow" seems like the obvious choice, since it's the simpler of the two.

Comment: This site takes a bit of a descriptivist stance: that was, we describe "English as she is spoke", and can't really speculate (much less dictate) how it will or should be used in the future (in the StackExchange vernacular, these questions are closed as "primarily opinion-based", aka subjective).  You can certainly ask if such a gender-neutral term has been coined, or if any has any currency.  I don't believe it has, though it's certainly possible.  As for picking "widow": because no one yet uses it that way, it's liable to cause confusion unless you explain yourself first, which is self-dfting

Comment: Predicting the future is always difficult, but with languages only doubly so, because that whole "wouldn't it make sense" affair is the very first thing that natural languages really really love to toss out of the window.

Comment: I don't think there is a single word for it yet. You can always use 'the deceased's surviving spouse'

Comment: @RegDwigнt 1) I thought "wouldn't it make sense" is the _only_ reliable thing about natural language and other things like consistency or syntax are the first to go out the window. 2) I can predict the future incredibly accurately in the next 1/2 second while driving. In fact I'

Comment: It would make sense, so start saying it.

Comment: @Dan Bron 'Let's not offer speculation or opinions. Let's analyze usage, present data, marshal authority, offer citations. You know the drill. For more on avoiding the subjective nature of the question as it stands, see my comment under it. – Dan Bron' Purloined from the deleted answer's comments, and data-banked for future use (hopefully :{ not required).

Comment: A similar question has been asked at Word Reference Forums (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/compound-words-with-mistress-stationmaster-and-stationmistress.3794645/#post-19380581). The only other point that I would make is that the question *"Would it make more sense to use a third, different word, ...?"* is answered by *"if it did, then there would be one"* Language very much follows the law of supply and demand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One good option is **surviving spouse**:

> A spouse who lives longer than the other spouse.
>   <sub>[US Legal](https://definitions.uslegal.com/s/spouse/)</sub>

---

This expression is pretty widespread and is used on the [Social Security webpage](https://www.ssa.gov/planners/survivors/ifyou.html):

> Benefits can be paid to the worker's children and the surviving spouse who is caring for the children even if the worker doesn't have the required number of credits.

It's also used on the [Office of Personnel Management Retire FAQ](https://www.opm.gov/faq/retire/May-I-receive-benefits-if-I-am-the-surviving-spouse-2.ashx) (another government site):

> If you are the surviving spouse of a deceased employee, recurring monthly payments may be made to you if your spouse completed at least 18 months of creditable civilian service and was covered under the Civil Service Retirement System (CSRS).

Comment: I thought of redefining widower as someone in a marriage who dies, and widowee as the surviving person in that marriage. Like mentor and mentee, trainer and trainee, etc.

Comment: It should be noted that *surviving spouse* is not any shorter than *widow or widower*, so it is debatable whether much is gained by replacing the latter with the former.